# Distinct Counting over period of time

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have a simple table that consists of user_id, action_date

```
user_id    action_date
user_001    2016-04-15
user_002    2016-04-15
user_003    2016-04-15
user_002    2016-04-15
user_001    2016-04-15
user_004    2016-04-16
user_005    2016-04-16
user_001    2016-04-16
user_001    2016-04-16
user_001    2016-04-16
```

and for every action_date in the database I need to check how many distinct users have been active in the period of 30 days counting back from that action_date.

I know I have to go back 30 days for every action_date and calculate distinct active users in that period, I tried something like this, but it doesn't work as intendent, as **I need distinct count for every 30 days period proceeding action_date**.

```
SELECT action_date, COUNT (DISTINCT user_id) from Table_1 where user_id IN
(SELECT user_id from Table_1
WHERE action_date Between DATEADD(day,-30,action_date) and action_date)
GROUP BY action_date
```

Comment: what output you are getting from this query ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a number for each distinct `action_date` in your table.

So, first you need a virtual table showing the action dates.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT action_date FROM Table_1
```

Then you need to join that virtual table to your original table in a way that picks out the 30-day ranges:

```
  SELECT a.action_date, b.user_id
    FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT action_date FROM Table_1
         ) a
    LEFT JOIN Table_1 b ON b.action_date >= a.action_date - INTERVAL 29 DAY
                       AND b.action_date <= a.action_date
```

Then you need to aggregate this result.

```
  SELECT a.action_date, COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id) user_count
    FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT action_date FROM Table_1
         ) a
    LEFT JOIN Table_1 b ON b.action_date >= a.action_date - INTERVAL 29 DAY
                       AND b.action_date <= a.action_date
   GROUP BY a.action_date
   ORDER BY a.action_date
```

I've written this out step by step in the hopes you'll see how to build your query using the *structured* aspect of *structured query language.*

It's also helpful, when writing a query like this, to troubleshoot each step along the way. If you write the whole thing out, it can be quite difficult to find problems.

(`- INTERVAL 29 DAY`?  You asked for a thirty day range. I've included the date in question and the 29 days preceding it. )

Notice that if your action_dates were `DATETIME` items, you'd need to make a few changes.

```
  SELECT DATE(a.action_date) action_date, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id) user_count
    FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT DATE(action_date) action_date FROM Table_1
         ) a
    LEFT JOIN Table_1 b ON b.action_date >= a.action_date - INTERVAL 29 DAY
                       AND b.action_date < a.action_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   GROUP BY DATE(a.action_date)
   ORDER BY DATE(a.action_date)
```

Notice how the date range, when you use `DATETIME` items, runs up until, but not including  (`<`), midnight on the day *after* the end date (`action_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT action_date, COUNT (DISTINCT user_id) from Table_1 where
action_date Between DATEADD(day,-30,action_date) and action_date
GROUP BY action_date
```

the above query is enough to fetch the results